# Can I transform a function result into a variable for another function in python/FLASK?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm learning Python 2.7 and FLASK. I have an exercise consuming the Spotify API, so with a function I get the ID of an artist.

Can I use the result of that function (the id) and store it as a variable so I can use it inside another API endpoint? Or how can I use that result?

Here's my code:

```
@app.route("/api/artist/<artist>")
def api_artist(artist):
    params = get_id(artist)
    return jsonify(params)

def get_id(artist):

    headers = {
        "client_id": "XxXXxxXXX",
        "cliente_secret": "XXXxxxxXXX"
    }

    response = requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + artist +"&type=artist", headers=headers)


    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.text)
        lista=[]
        response_dict = response.json()
        results = response_dict["artists"]
        items = results ["items"]
        for value in items:
            lista.append(value["id"])




    params = {
        "id": lista[0]
    }

    return params
```

This is the Spotify endpoint I trying to use: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}/top-tracks`

Comment: Can you explain more of what you are trying to do? Why do you only return `{"id": lista[0]}` instead of the *entire* artist?

Comment: @cricket_007 Because I only need the id of all the JSON information that comes out with the "search" endpoint.

Comment: Can you answer the first part of my question? Exactly what data are you expecting to see?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry I forgot to answer that, 

I want you to throw me the top-track of an artist, but instead of the user typing the artist's spotify id on the path, just write the name of the artist as well, my get_id (artist) function looks for the id and What I want is to know if there is a way to save the result of that function in a variable to be able to use it in another function and thus to replace the space of id in the url of the API.

I do not know if there is a better way to solve the problem, for now is the way I thought.

Comment: RESTful protocols should be "stateless", meaning that variables should never be "saved off" to a global variable. For example, you hit `/api/artist/3` and 5 other people hit `/api/artist/12`, you don't want any of those request to "save" any "application variable" and conflict with each other.

Comment: You could dump the Spotify API into a SQLite database (as answered), but what if an artist has a new song released? Then your database would be "stale" and you would need to use the Spotify API again to query for "fresh" data.

Answer (score 0):

REST API should be "stateless" and hence not a good idea as pointed out by @[cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007)

So here's what you do:
Make 2 REST API Calls and handle the personalization of the user artist preference on the client side

> 1.) Search the artist and get the ID and return it to the user(client) application
>
> 2.) Make a second REST API Call with the acquired id and fetch the top tracks

Hope this helps. Cheers!